# Why do bare git repos have an active branch?

Tags: git

Really, the question fits in the title. Bare repos don't have a working directory so what do they need an active branch for?

The only times I have noticed that there even is an active branch is when I attempted to force-push to the active branch of a remote repo and it didn't work. You then have to change it to some other branch, do your force-push, and change it back. I don't see the point in this but want to understand it so I'm less frustrated when I have to do it the next time.

Comment: You don't need to change the branch of the bare target repository when force pushing to it. How did you change the branch of the bare repository?

Comment: The purpose of the "active branch" of a bare repository is to specify which branch clones should automatically check out.

Comment: For what it's worth, you *can* push to the current branch of a bare repository; what you can't do is *delete* that branch.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Now I'm confused. I wanted to send you some commands + terminal output while clearly illustrate that it's not possible. [Apparently, it's possible.](https://pastebin.com/vTzxBhP4) I'm sure that I had the problem of not being able to force-push to a remote 3 times already after amending a commit I already pushed on my local machine. I changed the branch via `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/<branchname>`. And I found this command in the bash history of my raspi (which I use as a server) as expected. I looked it up to make sure I've not gone batshit crazy and have false memories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active branch is the local branch which gets automatically created and checked out in clones.

`git clone <url>` is basically these steps...

- `git init`
- `git remote add origin <url>`
- `git fetch origin`
- `git checkout -b <branch> origin/<branch>`

Initialize a repository, add a remote called "origin", copy everything from `origin` to remote tracking branches (ie. `origin/master`), create a local branch off `origin/<branch>`, and check it out.

`<branch>` is the active branch on the bare remote.

Comment: But why does this prevent one from force-pushing to that branch?

Comment: @UTF-8 It doesn't? Could you add some detail? [If you're using Github, there is the option to lock certain branches to prevent force pushes](https://help.github.com/articles/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/).

Comment: I didn't have this problem with GH, yet (because one always creates feature branches and merges them on the GH website, as you said). However, I have tons of non-code (just managing my documents and stuff) personal git repos on my raspi which I access via ssh and where I mostly commit directly on master. I then had cases where I wrote some text in a LaTeX file, committed my changes, pushed, and found a spelling error or something alike and wanted to amend the latest commit and push again. It didn't work without changing the act. branch. See also: The comment I just wrote below the question.

Comment: @UTF-8 Sorry, can't say more except I believe the active branch is a red herring. If it happens again, capture the command history and maybe ask another question.